# Заполнить input из массива js

Tags: html, javascript

Есть не большая ф-ция работающая по onclic - юзер заполняет поля input 1,input 2,input 3 и тд после чего нажимает кнопку и срабатывает ф-ция - а в функции есть массив с данными:

```
    var myvar = [  
    {val1:"слово",val2:'цифра',val3:"слово",}   
];
```

Как мне при отработке ф-ции передать зничение

```
myvar[val1]
```

в input 4?

Comment: Так?

    input.value = myvar.val1;

Comment: а как указать в ккой именно инпут нужно посылать значение?

Comment: вот так у меня получилось
   function getmesseg(){

 var date3 = '5';
 $('#example1').val(date3);
 var temp = $('#example1').val();
 alert(temp);
 };

Answer (score 1):

Вот так

```
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[3].value = myvar[0]['val1'];
```

Пример тут <a href="http://jsfiddle.net/Xk8Zz/">http://jsfiddle.net/Xk8Zz/</a>

C помощью jQuery

```
$('input').eq(3).val(myvar[0]['val1']);
```

Comment: вы в вашем примере посылаете данные из массива в инпут по его номеру- а как такое по id сделать?

Comment: ой, извените ступил, спасибо